# How to create trigger for auto renew

Tags: mysql, triggers

How to create trigger for auto renew ?

I have no idea how to create trigger for auto renew

This is my Table

```
  create table VIP( VipID char(10) not null,
 MemberID INT not null, 
 PackageID Char(10) not null,
 Vip_Expire Date null,
 DateofTransaction date null,
 Paymentchannel Char(20) null
```

In my case i need to auto update VIP_expire when it is expired.

[Update 30 days for every times that it's expire]

Comment: You should research events